# Why I cannot connect to Linux MSSQL (SQLEXPRESS) from my Windows computer?

Tags: sql-server, connection, debian

I just installed MSSQL on debian 8 (64bit) fallowing this steps on this [link](https://dev.to/nabbisen/microsoft-sql-server-2017-on-debian-n77). It installs ok, no errors, I can also use `sqsh -S localhost -U sa` and it connects and I can execute SQL commands normaly. I choose to install SQLExpress license, so I suppose that instance name is "\SQLEXPRESS"

I install MSSQL server on my "mini computer" that is connected to my router (which sets DHCP). With other devices connected to this router I can ping this "mini computer" and also in other side, from "mini computer" I can ping other devices. All devices are in Workgroup, and not in Domain. Also I can connect with SSL to this "mini computer".

But If I want to connect from my Windows computer from Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, I get error, that I cannot connect to this "mini computer": The parameter is incorrect! What I am doing wrong, is it possible to make connection like this, or I have to have domain server?

[image]

Comment: Named instances aren't supported on Linux.

Comment: @Larnu What do you mean by named instances? Should I just then leave IP address?

Comment: `\\192.16.8.106\SQLEXPRESS` is trying to connect the the named instance `SQLEXPRESS` on the server `192.16.8.106`; as SQL Server on Linux doesn't support named instances, there can be no instance called `SQLEXPRESS` (or with any name) on the Linux host..

Comment: @Larnu I didn't give any name during installation, I suppose that installation give it automaticly. If I give only IP address (192.168.8.106) It says that connection is established, but an existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote server.

Comment: *"I didn't give any name during installation"* No, because you **can't**; Linux *does not support named instances*... As for why the connection was forcibly closed, I suggest consulting the logs on the SQL Server; they'll likely give a more verbose reason as to why. As far as I know, SQL Server is not officially supported on Debian; so that could easily be your problem there.

Comment: @Larnu thanks I will try it to reinstall to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS as in MS site is described: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

when you get a message : 
the connection is established, but an existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote server
that means the connection is correct but this error could happen sometime for windows version, try it with other windows version and other SSMS version.